# React-native snap carousel / virtualized list rendering item at index

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-snap-carousel

I'm using *react-native-snap-carousel* to render a list of more than 100 items (this value can increase).

When the carousel is rendered, the first **14** items are rendered.

Then I need to user the `onSnapTo` method for an index which is out of the visible area and it has not being rendered yet. E.g.:

```
this.carousel.snapToItem(90)
```

The carousel instead of render the 90th item, it renders the last in the visible area: 14.

Is there a way to move the carousel to index 90 and render items around that index programmatically?

Comment: It seems an [issue](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/363) is currently open in the repo. Have you tried changing `initialNumToRender`?

Comment: Thanks, I had not seen that issue. Yes I tried with initialNumberToRender but I wanted to avoid to render the whole list of items, especially when having many elements.